# Forum - Topics ordered by last activity over multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forum

I am currently creating a forum with php and sql. 
My problem is how to get the topics into the right order assuming that there are a total of 200 and 15 per Page and I'm on page number 10.

I can't select per id because if someone posts into one of these topics the timestamp 
of that specific topic gets updated -> the newest on top.

For the first page something like that could be okay:

```
select * from topics order by time desc limit 15
```

but for the next page I would need the timestamp of the last topic on the page before.

If I could select a specific table by index relative to the timestamp order without the need for the actual index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the [MySQL documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for the second argument of the LIMIT clause:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

Syntax:

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

Example:

```
-- page 2:
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 15, 15;
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 15;

-- page 3:
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 30, 15;
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 30;

-- page n:
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT (n-1)*15, 15;
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET (n-1)*15;
```

Comment: i tried the last one and i cant it get to work with the variable, only with numeric constants. 
($n-1)*15 ..am i missing some quotes oder something?

Comment: nevermind, just multiplied n before and just wrote $n into the query.
Now it works, thanks for the quick answer. i would like to upvote you but my reputation seems to be too low